# NotImplementedError: The gflags library must be installed to use tools.run(). Please install gflags or preferrably switch to using tools.run_flow()

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am developing GAE django non-rel app. I am facing gflags related error.

> NotImplementedError: The gflags library must be installed to use
>   tools.run(). Please install gflags or preferrably switch to using
>   tools.run_flow()

To solve this error, i downloaded glags.py and gflags_validators.py and put them into my project's root folder.

By above solution i got another error.

```
EOFError at /pages
EOF when reading a line

Exception Value:
EOF when reading a line
Exception Location: D:\jatin\Project\GAE_django\non-rel_django1.5\oauth2client\old_run.py in run,  line 149
```

Comment: That's impossible to read. Is there any reason why you couldn't click the text that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and then paste the actual text here?

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
pip install python-gflags
```

or

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade python-gflags
```